# I want to add MBProgressHUD in NSObject class

Tags: iphone, ios, mbprogresshud

I am uploading data on server from my NSObject class, now i want to show MBProgressHUD when that data is uploading, I know how to show MBProgressHUD with ViewController but dont know how to show it with NSObject class.

Comment: import MBProgressHUD in that class and start using

Comment: but how can i do this   [self.view addSubview:HUD];   in NSObject class

Comment: and if i dont add subview it will not display

Comment: will you have a reference of calling this NSobject class in your view, if yes means use custom delegate and add MBProgressHUD  to your view

Comment: Depending on what you want to HUD to look like, you could try using an [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD). It doesn't require you to pass it a view controller so its easy to show it from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

```
AppDelegate* delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.window addSubview:HUD];
...
[HUD removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: assumes you have a window property on the app delegate.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve this kind of problems. The most common one is using the delegation pattern, although you can use blocks, KVO, or Notifications.

You should start by creation a protocol, so you can communicate between your `UIViewController` and your `NSObject` that makes the calls. Although you don't need one to create this communication, you should use it to have a more flexible code.

Normally, I would do something like this:

```
@protocol CommunicationDelegate <NSObject>

@required

-(void)communicationSucceed;

-(void)communicationFailedWithError:(NSError*)anError;
```

Inside your `NSObject`, you will have a `weak` reference for an object that complies with the protocol `CommunicationDelegate`. In your .h you should have something like this:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) id <CommunicationDelegate> communicationDelegate;
```

Just before you actually start your work with the `NSObject`, you should do:

```
myObjectThatWillDoSomething.communicationDelegate = self;
```

At this moment you have a valid reference between your `UIViewController` and your `NSObject`. Inside your UIViewController's .h file, add this:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <CommunicationDelegate>
```

So your `UIViewController` complies to the `CommunicationDelegate` protocol.

You can now start your `MBProgressHUD` from your `UIViewController`. Once your `NSObject` has done his work, you can either call:

```
[communicationDelegate communicationSucceed];
```

or

```
[communicationDelegate communicationFailedWithError:anError]; //anError is used to describe what went wrong
```

Once (one of) those methods are called, you can remove your `MBProgressHUD`. Understand that this methods are called inside your `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload your NSObject, a view is displayed, right? So display your HUD in that view. You may need to create a delegate to notify the view when the download begin, when it ends and if there is an error.

Comment: but i want to close HUD from NSObject calss that be problem

Answer (score 0):

Use  NSNotification Center to stop Indicator , Declare NSNotification with listening method in view controller . And post notification from Webservice file . Stop indicator in listening method of Notification center .

This link will help you

Answer (score 0):

Create a delegate protocol on your uploader object

```
@protocol UploaderThingyDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)stuffStarted;

-(void)stuffEnded;

@end

@interface UploaderThingy : NSObject

@property (weak) id<UploaderThingyDelegate> delegate;
```

Set your relevant View or ViewController as the uploaders delegate and trigger the MBProgressHUD add/remove there.

Answer (score -1):

These Below Code Works fine in NSObject File

Step 1: Download the https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Step 2: Add the Delegate MBProgressHUDDelegate

Step 3: Declare Instance MBProgressHUD *HUD;

Step 4: Write Code Where u want:

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:HUD];

HUD.delegate = self;
HUD.labelText = @"Processing";
[HUD show:YES];
```